# Inconsistent "UND" value in node fields

Tags: nodes, theming

I'm manually printing my node fields on its template (node--TYPE.tpl.php). Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="press-year col-md-12">
        <h2><?php print $year; ?></h2>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And my hook_preprocess_node() looks something like:

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    switch ($vars['type']) {
        case "my_type":
           if (isset($vars["field_year"]["und"][0])) {
              $vars["year"] = $vars["field_year"]["und"][0]["value"];
          }
        break;
    }
}
```

The output is fine to all fields; however, when I view the node as administrator, no output is printed. I listed all the variables from the hook to see what was happening with the following code.

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    var_dump($vars);
    ....
}
```

I'm getting all fields without the "UND" value, `$vars["field_year"][0]["value"]` instead of `$vars["field_year"]["und"][0]["value"]`.

Do you have any clue why this happens?

Comment: This is definitely a Drupal 7 site?

Comment: In Drupal 7 hook_preprocess_node is not normally invoked on the node edit form (ie. when you go to 'node/xxx/edit'), there must be a different problem?

Comment: @jamestsymp yes, D7

Comment: @AliceHeaton I've edited my post. I meant seeing the node as admin (E.g.: /node/27)

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that it is D7 then I assume there must be another module that is editing the structure of the nodes as I've always had the language passed through.

`$vars["field_year"][0]["value"]` is what you get from Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with D7.  The solution for me was to use field_get_items(...) for reading the node data.

```
$year_items = field_get_items('node', $variables['node'], 'field_year');
$year = $year_items[0]['value'] + 1;
```

I found the post on [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) very helpful.  It does seem strange that we shouldn't use the $variables provided to the preprocessor and template to read and modify the template variables.  I must be missing something.